# how to retrieve value from member which is generic data type

Tags: java

I have a getter method `getSelected()` as follows

```
public abstract class AbstractController<T> implements Serializable {
     @Inject
    private AbstractFacade<T> ejbFacade;
    private Class<T> itemClass;
    private T selected;

    public T getSelected() {
        System.out.println("selected:"+selected);
        return selected;
    }
}
```

In the `System.out.println("selected:"+selected);` statement it prints the following variant 1

```
selected:entities.Farm[ farmPK=entities.FarmPK[ farmid=20, deviceid=102 ] ]
```

or variant 2

```
selected:entities.Layoutmonitor[ layoutmonitorPK=entities.LayoutmonitorPK[ layoutid=18, monitorpointid=59, deviceid=102 ] ].
```

Depending on the users selection on the user interface, the selected value is displayed. If farm entry is selected it displays variant 1, if Layoutmonitor entry is selected it displays variant 2.

Can anybody help me to retrieve the value of layoutid and type layoutmonitor from the 'selected' field if user selects layoutmonitor. Similarly for farm during runtime.

Comment: Are `Farm` and `Layoutmonitor` open to modification ? What do these 2 classes have in common ? Only an ID ?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about something specific without giving specifics. There is a general answer to the general question you are asking, which is `how does one abstract class work with another abstract class through generics`, which is a little bit complicated and you should have a simpler example.

In your case, `AbstractController` is the "abstract controller" class. A concrete implementation of it might be "FileController extends AbstractController".

Your second class is of type `T`. In your question you say that anything of type `T` has at least two properties, `layoutId` and `layoutMonitor`. So, anything that can represent T must have those two properties, and since it's generic, it is implied that there is more than one class. This is usually done through an abstract class, let's call it `SelectorBase`. `SelectorBase` might look like this:

```
public abstract class SelectorBase {
    int layoutId;
    Object loytoutMonitor;
}
```

A concrete version might be `TextSelector`, defined as `TextSelector extends SelectorBase`. No need to show the class here. In order to have you're `AbstractController` class work on any extension of `SelectorBase`, you declare that in the generics like so:

```
public abstract class AbstractController<T extends SelectorBase> {
    public T getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

The `T extends SelectorBase` is the answer to your question. T is defined as a class that extends `SelectorBase`. This is how you "retrieve the value of layoutid and type layoutmonitor from the 'selected' field ". You use this class `genericized interface` like so:

```
FileControlller c = new FileController<TextSelector>();
TextSelector s = c.getSelected();
int layoutId = s.layoutId;
Object layoutMonitor = s.layoutMonitor();
.. and so on
```

I don't know `Farm` is or `layoutObject` is because I have no idea what code you're talking about. In general, though, this is how you handle the situation you described.

Comment: what is c in the code? how should I initialize c. can you please  explain me clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using instanceof operator:

```
public T getSelected() {
 if(selected instanceof Layoutmonitor){
 //print layoutid and type layoutmonitor 
 }
     return selected;
    }
```